# Maven deploy on Nexus 2.11.4-01 does not complete

Tags: maven, nexus

I am using 'mvn clean deploy' as a maven goal to deploy an artifact on our local Nexus repository (2.11.4-01). It starts the upload (the artifact is a jar file) normally but does not end with the usual **'uploaded'** confirmation. It in turn starts uploading the next artifact (which is the pom file of the jar file it thinks got uploaded) and maven fails the execution at that point. Any help would be really appreciated.
**Note:** The same behavior works for another project but for a smaller file size (less than 1 MB)

Here is the information on what happens:

Uploading: /xyz.jar
 4 KB
8 KB
12 KB
16 KB

### 20 KB

### ----

**9034 KB**

Uploading: /xyz.pom
 4 KB
8 KB
12 KB
16 KB
17 KB

**FAILURE occurs at this point**

**Stack trace:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project xyz: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact xyz.jar 
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project xyz: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact xyz.jar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: 
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: 
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:156)
    ... 21 more
 Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: 
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:259)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:136)
    ... 22 more
 Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: 
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:945)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:940)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:864)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.put(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:465)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:253)
    ... 24 more
```

Here is the build goal from the pom file:

```
                <!-- JAVADOCS -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <stylesheet>maven</stylesheet>
                        <footer>Generated ${maven.build.timestamp}</footer>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Have you checked the log files of Nexus?

Comment: I tried with Maven 3.0.2 and the latest version 3.3.3. The Nexus logs show nothing.

Comment: Could you post your pom?

Comment: I have added the jar build goal to my original Question. Anything specific you are looking in the pom? The pom is owned by the app. team and  I may not be able to post it out here. Sorry about that.

Comment: I was able to figure out the real issue after submitting a ticket to the sonatype support. It appeared that the proxy server was not allowing the upload to Nexus. As I disabled the proxy from the settings.xml, the upload worked like a charm. Thanks all for helping with this. Not sure how to mark this as resolved though.